# Convert String to BigInteger in C++

Tags: c++, string, biginteger

I'm using the BigInteger library. However when converting from string to BigInteger I summon the error "no matching function for call BigInteger(string&)".

How should one convert from between the two without invoking an error?

Here is a snippit of my code:

```
      #include "BigIntegerLibrary.hh"

      str1=randomStrGen(1);
      str2=randomStrGen(1);

      BigInteger s1 = new BigInteger(str1);
      BigInteger s2 = new BigInteger(str2);
```

BigInteger Library downloaded from https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/,
2010.04.30 Release

Comment: Which BigInteger library are you using?  Link to download site?  Where is you include statement?

Comment: @DougCoburn Just added the version info

Comment: @CinCout I guess there are multiple BigInteger Libraries for this, I'll have a look for another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can convert a `std::string` to `BigInteger`:

```
std::string s("3141592653589793238462643383279");
BigInteger f = stringToBigInteger(s);
```

Note that the method `stringToBigInteger()` is declared in `BigIntegerUtils.hh`.

This and many other sample usages of the library can be found [here](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/bigint.git/blob/HEAD:/sample.cc).

Comment: I deleted my duplicate answer... you beat me to it.